# Getting data from a closed workbook based on contents of a cell in the open worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to try to get data from a single cell in a closed workbook/worksheet but the file name is dependent on a cell in the open workbook/worksheet. 
This is the code I'm starting with but can't get it to work correctly.

```
Private Function GetValue(path, file, sheet, ref)

path = "Z:\Jobs\"
file = "4817.xlsx"
sheet = "RTR1"
ref = "A13"

 '   Retrieves a value from a closed workbook
Dim arg As String

 '   Make sure the file exists
If Right(path, 1) <> "\" Then path = path & "\"
If Dir(path & file) = "" Then
    GetValue = "File Not Found"
    Exit Function
End If

 '   Create the argument
arg = "'" & path & "[" & file & "]" & sheet & "'!" & _
Range(ref).Range("A1").Address(, , xlR1C1)

 '   Execute an XLM macro
GetValue = ExecuteExcel4Macro(arg)
End Function
```

```
Sub TestGetValue()

path = "Z:\Jobs\"
file = "Macine Planning.xlsx"
sheet = "Data"

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For r = 1 To 30
    For C = 1 To 18
        a = Cells(r, C).Address
        Cells(r, C) = GetValue(path, file, sheet, a)
    Next C
Next r

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You understand that you are rewriting the values of the parameters that you are passing into the GetValue helper function?

Comment: I see you call `GetValue(path, file, sheet, a)`  in `TestGetValue()`, but in `GetValue` you don't use the variables that are passed through, they get overwritten by the first four declarations.  Also, how isn't your code working? Is it pulling incorrect info, no info, erroring, etc.?  Edit: Bah, @Jeeped is a little quicker pointing out the overwriting, with his fancy-schmancy Surface :P

Comment: so I think it is pulling the correct piece of data over but I need the file = "4817.xlsx" line to reference a cell in the active worksheet.... and I don't know how to do that.

Comment: `file = activesheet.range(<a cell in the active worksheet>).text`

Comment: @BruceWayne - Yeah, fancy-schmancy as in 'three times the price for less power, less storage and a bat-crap-crazy keyboard'.

Comment: When looking to a mapped drive on a server what should the path be? Should it be the full path or the Mapped network drive Z:\Jobs\

Comment: I can't get the file = activesheet.range line to work. I keep get an application defined or object-defined error. any suggestions?